# Is there any way or hotkey for custom screen scale setting in Windows 11?

Tags: desktop-customization, windows-11

I share my laptop with my brother and we both use different scale settings; I use 125 and he uses 100.

How can I get a context menu for Windows 11 or a hotkey to switch the setting for me without logging out or when I change it myself through the windows setting app, it does not require a logout to take effect?

Surely, there has to be a way that does not require a logout. Tempted to ask a windows modder, they may know a way to use calls to call forward the request rather than a regedit that requires a reboot.

If you have any ideas let me know.

[image: Win 11 Scale Setting]

Comment: What do you do that requires you to logout?

Comment: I dont do anything, but windows 11 for some reason lags forever. takes 1 minute to change the layout. wondering if there is a way to keybind the action rather than having to go through the laggy interface

Answer (score 0):

You won't get away from the need to logout/login, unless you and your
brother use different logins/accounts.

When using two accounts, you would in this case use Switch User
instead of Logoff, to switch immediately to the other user session
with its own scaling.

You would leave your session running in the background while your brother
is using the computer, then switch from his session back to your session.